# Opposite of git cherry-pick?

Tags: git

Is there an effective opposite of git cherry-pick? For instance some time ago, I had to make some temporary changes to disable a set of features due to a business process not being ready.  Now that that business process is ready I'd like to simply remove the commits and their effects.  While I could of course just look at the diffs of those commits and figure out what all needed to be done, it would be interesting to know if those commits way back in the history could be un-done without resetting and losing all that came after them.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The automated way to undo changes made by another commit is `git revert`.

Comment: This is NOT the opposite use `git rebase -i` instead as the @Kyralessa answer explains

Comment: Note that the commit to revert doesn't have to be present in the current branch at all. It could e.g. have been squashed into other commits and remain in `git reflog` or in another branch — in this case `git revert` will still work.

Answer (score 34):

`git revert` isn't the opposite of `git cherry-pick`.  `git rebase -i` is.

`git revert` adds a new commit that removes the changes made by one or more old commits.  It doesn't remove the original commits.

`git rebase -i` will show you a list of commits from your current commit, going back to the last commit not on your upstream branch.  Then you can edit, rearrange, change the commit message, and even delete commits from this list.

Keep in mind that if you've already pushed the commits you want to remove, you'll need to OK removing them with your teammates, because they'll have to make adjustments once you push the new history with the removed commits.

Comment: This is great to know!  While rebase -i technically answers the question and may be cleaner in the long run, git revert satisfies the problem I expressed.

Comment: "`git revert` adds a new commit that removes the changes made by one or more old commits." This sounds *exactly* like the opposite of `git cherry-pick`. Perhaps "inverse" would be a better word than "opposite".

Comment: If `git cherry-pick` adds a commit, then the opposite would be to remove that commit.  Not to add _another_ commit.

Comment: @Kyralessa what is opposite probably depends on what point you stress :)

Comment: @Kyralessa What is inverse of `a^b=c`? is it `log(c,a)` or is it root(c,b)?
(probably depends on which "property" is most important to you)

Comment: Back to Git… Both suggested commands can remove the effects of an existing commit. From a Git user’s point of view, `git rebase -i` is great on a branch that can be rebased while `git revert` comes in handy on a branch that cannot. Since the actual situation hasn’t been stated in the question, both should be mentioned.

Comment: If you are working on a branch then there is a big difference...that is, when you merge your branch back into mainline. If you revert a commit then those commits will be reverted when you merge your branch into mainline as well. But if you cherry picked commits into your original branch then only your changes to existing files (i.e. create, delete, edit files) will be merged into mainline. Which commits you cherry picked won't matter...git only merges in your file edits/diff.

Comment: Although the opossite of `cherry-pick` (`add a commit by ref`) is `remove a commit by ref`. But it is best to use `git revert` "add a new commit that revert a change by specific ref". Since it wont rewrite history. One exception is when you want to remove sensitive information

Comment: `rebase -i` is only the opposite of a `cherry-pick` insofar as it has the capability to completely remove a commit. It's the opposite of *any* type of commit.
i.e. `rebase` can be the opposite of any commit; `revert` is the opposite of `cherry-pick` (imo).

Comment: @noelicus `git cherry-pick` adds a commit that wasn't there before.  `git revert` doesn't remove that commit.  It removes some (but not all) of the _effects_ of that commit...but it doesn't remove the commit.  It adds _another_ commit.  So it's not the opposite of `git cherry-pick`.  Granted, it might be close enough for some people's purposes, depending on what they want to do.

Comment: I mostly agree, except for "the opposite of". The OP does ask for the commits to be "removed". What they actually mean by that is spelled out, but is implied in "I could of course just look at the diffs of those commits and figure out what all needed to be done". They seem to want new changes that undo. rebase -i *might* be appropriate if the branch isn't pushed and shared. cherry-pick specifically doesn't mess with the history (by creating a new commit), imo the opposite of that is to undo those changes as a set of new changes. So I guess I think the title doesn't match the question!